# I'm confused about the ".connect()" method; does it belong to the imported "mysql" module? If so, shouldn't it be written as: con.mysql.connect()?

Tags: mysql, node.js

In Python, I have to explicitly write

```
from my_module import my_find_index
```

Before I can use the `my_find_index` function without typing the whole
`index = my_module.my_find_index('dog')`

```
animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'horse']
#Get the index of "dog"
index = animals.my_find_index('dog')
```

In this code, there's no explicit import of the connect() method:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({

  host: "localhost",

  user: "yourusername",

  password: "yourpassword"

});

con.connect(function(err) {

  if (err) throw err;

  console.log("Connected!");

});`
```

`.connect()` is a `mysql` method. Shouldn't it be:

```
con.mysql.connect(function(err) {

     //Some code

});`
```

Comment: Why do you believe that the object returned by the `mysql.createConnection()` method (here represented by `con`) should have an attribute `mysql` on it? Can you link to a source or documentation page which demonstrates that this should be the case? Why would you need to explicitly import an attribute on an object…?

Comment: @esqew here: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp

Comment: I’m not sure you’ve understood the question - nothing on the page you’ve linked indicates the `con` variable here should be expected to have an attribute of its own named `mysql` which is why it’s abundantly unclear to me why you believe this to be “correct”. `mysql` certainly exists - you’ve declared it; `con.mysql`, a reference to a *property* of the object `con`, does not necessarily. Are you aware of how object oriented languages operate, fundamentally?

Answer (score -1):

You are importing the SQL and are declaring it as con same way that you would do like example:

```
int number = 5;
```

So anytime you want to use SQL you just have to use the name that you give to the variable of that type.